# Using promises with mongoose functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm new to promises. And I'm trying to use them with mongoose query functions like `find()` and `findById()`. Everything seems to work but I'm not sure if this is the correct way of chaining `then`. The objective of using promises is to eliminate callback hell but the way I'm chaining `then` looks very similar to callbacks. Is there a better way to write this route?

```
router.get('/homehr/employees/new', middleware.isLoggedInAsHR, (req, res) => {
Department.find({})
    .exec()
    .then((allDepartments) => {
        Employee.findById(req.user.employee.id)
        .exec()
        .then((foundEmployee) => {
            res.render('hr/employees/new', {
                departments: allDepartments,
                employee: foundEmployee,
                blogs: allBlogs
            });
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        req.flash('error', err.message);
        return res.redirect('back');
    });
});
```

Comment: You should definitely switch to `async/await`. This is the ultimate callback hell solution.

Comment: You seems to miss Your Blog fetching from database , but using allBlogs as variable.

Comment: The Blog fetching is done outside this route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Routes doesn't seems to have dependency of fetching models in sequence. So You can write this in more better way as follow:

```js
router.get('/homehr/employees/new', middleware.isLoggedInAsHR, async (req, res) => {
   try{
      const allDepartments = await Department.find({});
      const foundEmployee = await Employee.findById(req.user.employee.id);
      res.render('hr/employees/new', {
          departments: allDepartments,
          employee: foundEmployee,
          blogs: allBlogs
      });
   }catch(err){
       console.log(err);
       req.flash('error', err.message);
       return res.redirect('back');
   }
)};
```

Comment: This worked thanks a lot for your answer. I didn't learn async/await yet but this seems to get rid of code indentation problem.